# Windows 10 and RDC Manager v2.7 missing cursor PowerShell ISE

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2012, powershell-ise

In Windows 7 no problems. Last week had to upgrade to Windows 10. Now I my mouse cursor disappears in the PowerShell ISE in Server 2012 R2. I tried [Console]::CursorSize = 25 from another post, but got an error. This is rather annoying. Please help. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust your Windows 10 DPI to recommended 100%:

**Settings -> System ->Display**, change **scale and layout**

And then also disable the high DPI scaling behavior for RDC:

1. Right click RDC application.
2. Under **Compatibility** tab, check "**Override high DPI scaling behavior**." box.
3. Choose **Scaling performed by "System".**

[image]